# Proving that a determinant is non zero

Tags: determinant, matrix-equations

Show that the following determinant is non-zero:

$$\overbrace{ \begin{vmatrix}
1 & 1 & \dots & 1\\
2^{m+1}-1^{m+1} & 2^m-1^m & \dots & 2^1-1\\
3^{m+1}-2^{m+1} & 3^m-2^m & \dots & 3^1-2^1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\vdots \\
(m+1)^{m+1}-m^{m+1} & (m+1)^m-m^m & \dots & 1 \\
\end{vmatrix}}^{m+1 \text{ times}} \neq 0$$

I tried to proceed by induction but I couldn't find a way to reduce it to a smaller determinant of the same  type. 
I don't know any other ways to proceed(maybe show it is invertible by construction of its inverse?) 
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The use of elementary row operations will help make this into a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix), and from there the nonzero determinant is shown by a cute proof that is worth remembering.